# How to get data in one middleware from another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, middleware

I have two middleware functions attached to my app get request which works fine.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

function fun1 (req, res, next) {
    console.log('this is fun1')
    next()
}

function fun2 (req, res, next) {
   console.log('this is fun2')
   next()
}

app.get('/', fun1, fun2, function (req, res, next) {
   res.send('User Info')
})
app.listen(8080, () => console.log(`Listening on port 8080!`))
```

Now if I try to do `next('test')` in `fun1` then it bypass `fun2` and does `'test'` output in browser window instead of `'User Info'` which is correct. But how do I get data in fun2? I need to pass something from fun1 and get it in fun2 for further validation.

Answer (score 2):

Assign it to `req`. You will have access to the same request and response objects through all middlewares.

Note that `next('test')` does *not respond to the client* or at least it is not meant to. It is meant to handle errors. Without an error handler and in development mode, Express shows these errors in the browser.

Read on:

[Error handling in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by attaching a key-value pair with req` object.

Now how to do this,

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

function fun1 (req, res, next) {
    req.MY_VAR = 'MY_VAL';  // setting the value
    console.log('this is fun1')
    next()
}

function fun2 (req, res, next) {
   let myVar = req.MY_VAR; // retrieving the value
   console.log(myVar); // MY_VAL
   console.log('this is fun2')
   next()
}

app.get('/', fun1, fun2, function (req, res, next) {
   res.send('User Info')
})
app.listen(8080, () => console.log(`Listening on port 8080!`))
```

Now, why not next()? Generally, the value passed in `next()` will be received by the error argument in `app.get('/', function (err, req, res, next) {} );`